# How to import a given csv located inside one of the files that are themselves inside a zip?

Tags: r, csv, zip

Let's imagine a zip "a0" that contains 3 files "a01", "a02" and "a03".
Using R, how to import a given csv (e.g. "ax.csv") that we don't know in which file is it?

NB : it is assumed that this given csv is unique in the entire zip, but that there may be other csv named differently.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unzip`. The first line gets the names of the files in the zip file.  We then grep out the file we want.  Change the pattern to whatever you are looking for.  Finally the second unzip call extracts the csv file and we read it in. No packages are used.

```
nms <- unzip("test.zip", list = TRUE)$Name
csv_name <- grep("csv$", nms, value = TRUE)
if (length(csv_name) != 1) stop("cannot determine which file to extract")
unzip("test.zip", files = csv_name)
read.csv(csv_name)
```

Comment: @GG: considering now that there are many zip that each contains many files, is it possible to rbind all the scattered csv that have the same name, e.g. 'XY.CSV'? (knowing that there is only one 'XY.CSV' per zip)

Comment: If you know the name of the file in the zip files, e.g. "my.csv" and iff they all have the same header then replace the first line with `nms <- "my.csv"` put the entire thing into a function `f` which inputs the zipfile name and outputs the data frame and use `do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, f))` where filenames is a character vector of the filenames of the zip files.

Comment: @GG: Thanks, but I'm not confortable with functions. I just posted the case on .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72592418/how-to-rbind-similar-csv-files-that-are-scattered-in-many-different-zip-files-u. Hoping that you will make an interesting proposal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use bash, you could `unzip` outside R, `grep` and `awk` the filepath, and finally in R `read.csv`. Might be much faster.

```
x <- system("unzip -c baz.zip | grep 'foo.csv' | awk '{print $2}'", int=TRUE)
read.csv(unzip('baz.zip', x))
#               X  mpg cyl disp
# 1     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160
# 2 Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160
# 3    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108
```

---

*Data*

```
system('mkdir dir1 dir2')
write.csv(mtcars[1:3, 1:3], './dir2/foo.csv')
write.csv(NULL, './dir1/bar.csv')
system('zip -r baz.zip dir1 dir2')
```

Comment: Thanks Jay. Surely a relevant approach; however, I do not known bash script (unix?) and the suggestion from GG works well. Hope that your proposal will help other people.

Comment: @demon Yes, bash lives on unix-alikes. However, you can also proceed similarly under other OS's,  i.e. unzip in the shell and not in R.